# Reduce a set expression in Mahematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, sets, subset

For example:

Given $ A\subset B $ reduce $\left [ (B\triangle C )\bigcap (A-B)\bigcap (A \triangle B) \right ]\bigcup B $

$A \triangle B$ denotes the symmetric difference of the two sets.

#### Edit

Possible results

A, B, C, U, $ \phi $

Comment: What Mathematica operator are you expressing with Δ?

Comment: You should also give the result you expect to get from reducing your example expression under the given condition.

Comment: Symmetric difference

Comment: You should express your problem in Mathematica terms, not general set-theoretical terms. Please express your example expression in Mathematica syntax,

Comment: [(b Xor c) && Complement[a, b] && (a Xor b)] v b // 
 Simplify -> Assuming  a C b <---error

Comment: In your 2nd comment, you appear to be confusing Boolean algebra with set theory.

Comment: How is that, can you illustrate !!!

Comment: In Mathematica `Complement` acts on lists treated as sets; `Xor` ,`And`,`Or` act on sequences of truth values (`True`, `False`). Entirely different domains. You can't combine them the way you did in your comment and expect to get a meaningful result.

Comment: The truth is I am new to mathematics, I use it to check, I read a lot but I mess with the commands, besides I do not speak English, that may confuse me

Comment: Good evening, and thanks so far

Comment: Hello ,Someone ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set theory operations can be expressed through Boolean operations.  Your expression is equivalent to

```
(Xor[b, c] && (a && ! b) && Xor[a, b]) || b
```

Think of `a` as standing for the statement $x \in A$, etc. Then e.g. $x \in (A - B)$ is equivalent to $x \in A \wedge x \notin B$.  Thus for $A - B$ we write `a && !b`.  Similarly, the symmetric difference is equivalent to `Xor`.

The expression above can be simplified to

```
Simplify[(Xor[b, c] && (a && ! b) && Xor[a, b]) || b]
(* (a && c) || b *)
```

We still need to use the fact that $A \subset B$. Think of this as $x \in A \Rightarrow x \in B$.  Thus

```
Simplify[Implies[a, b] && %]
(* b *)
```

The result is `b`, i.e. $B$.

Comment: I understood everything except the && % of the last line, you would be so kind
To explain to me what is similar, thank you for your time $ \left ( A-B \right )^{c}-\left ( B-C \right )^{c}\Rightarrow (A-B-C)^{^{c}} $ the last

Comment: Select `%` and press F1, or see  here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/12

Comment: ok,I already understood, how could simplify that with complements and with implies